# Cordova gradle version

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, gradle, visual-studio-cordova

Is there a way to setup gradle version for cordova project in visual studio?

build.gradle file contains the following string:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
```

But I need:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. We do not directly expose this setting in our tools. However, you can manually configure the platform to use a different version of Gradle. Please see the Apache documentation, here:

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/

(Disclosure: I work on the tools for apache Cordova in visual studio at Microsoft)

Comment: Too bad! in this docs does not exposed neither name for system variable nor example of it((
How I can change gradle version?

Answer (score 10):

For anyone else interested in updating the Gradle version used by Cordova, create this **system environment variable**:

```
CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL
https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.5-all.zip
```

To use a different version, get the proper link from [here](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/).

**For complete guide see [Upgrading Gradle for Cordova mobile apps in Windows](https://www.andreszsogon.com/upgrading-gradle-version-for-apache-cordova-mobile-apps/)**

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to andreszs solution is to modify `platforms\android\cordova\lib\builders\GradleBuilder.js`:

```
var distributionUrl = process.env['CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL'] || http\\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

Comment: And remember to do it again each time you remove and add the android platform..

Comment: This solution is identical to editing files inside node_modules. Definitely a NO-NO.